# How to serve specific static files with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have queries like `/api/lang?lang=en` which I want to serve with nginx as `/server/i18n-angular/en.json`. How can I do that?

I have the following directory structure:

```
/public/
/server/i18n-angular/en.json
```

I have the following configuration, but nginx says it is wrong to use index directive at that point.

```
server {
  root /public
  ...
  location /api/lang {
    if ($args ~* "\?lang=(.+)") {
      set $language $1;
      index ../server/i18n-angular/$language.json;
    }
  }
}
```

What directive should I use instead of `index`?

Comment: I think you'll find more people to answer this kind of question on serverfault..

Comment: thx, I'll put it up there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /api/lang {
    alias /server/i18n-angular;
    rewrite ^ /$arg_lang.json;
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

"index" specifies index file for displaying a folder, so it's not what you need.

You require "rewrite" instead:

```
location /api/lang {
    alias /server/i18n-angular;
    if ($args ~* "\?lang=(.+)") {
      set $language $1;
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$language.json;
    }
}
```